# Wrap Observable.FromEventPattern with Observable.Create

Tags: c#, .net, observable, rx.net

Which is the difference between this (taken from [RxCookbook on GitHub](https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/Model/PropertyChange.md)):

```
public static IObservable<TProperty> OnPropertyChanges<T, TProperty>(this T source, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property)
    where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    return  Observable.Create<TProperty>(o=>
    {
        var propertyName = property.GetPropertyInfo().Name;
        var propertySelector = property.Compile();

        return Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
                        handler => handler.Invoke,
                        h => source.PropertyChanged += h,
                        h => source.PropertyChanged -= h)
                    .Where(e => e.EventArgs.PropertyName == propertyName)
                    .Select(e => propertySelector(source))
                    .Subscribe(o);
    });
}
```

And this (written by myself):

```
public static IObservable<TProperty> OnPropertyChanges<T, TProperty>(this T source, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property)
    where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    var propertyName = property.GetPropertyInfo().Name;
    var propertySelector = property.Compile();

    return Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
                    handler => handler.Invoke,
                    h => source.PropertyChanged += h,
                    h => source.PropertyChanged -= h)
                .Where(e => e.EventArgs.PropertyName == propertyName)
                .Select(e => propertySelector(source));
}
```

I think that in the second block of code, `propertyName` and `propertySelector` will be evaluated when `OnPropertyChanges` is called and in the first block these variables will be evaluated every time someone subscribes to the observable. However, I can't figure out if/why the first block is preferrable to the second one, and why did the author of the first block decided to use `Observable.Create`.

Comment: Why not ask the author(s) why they did what they did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from the author of the first block of code on [GitHub](https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/issues/53#issuecomment-321684664):

> My stance on this is that calling a method that returns an IObservable should do nothing. It is the subscription to that returned value that should invoke any side effects or processing.
>
> If a subscription cost needs to be amortised across numerous subscriptions then the various multicast options in Rx should be applied.
>
> In this specific case, the argument is weak, however it then muddies the pattern and opens the door for other methods to "do work" without a subscription. I see this as a very common mistake and a source of race conditions and leaking resources (think opening a connection, starting a timer etc)

Comment: It makes sense to me as well, Observable.Create seems like a thin wrapper after all. If I were to subscribe and unsubscribe very often I would test the overhead of repeatedly calling  Expression Tree operations, but apart of this I asked just to check if I was missing something, which seems it's not the case, just a matter of personal preference of the author in this code.